# Homeomorphism/ homotopy types of non-negatively curved manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

A (special case of a) theorem of Gromov says for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a constant $C(n)$ such that for any smooth connected closed $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with non-negative sectional curvature the sum of all of its Betti numbers is at most $C(n)$.

On the other hand, for $n=2$  only sphere, torus, real projective plane, and (possibly- I do not know) connected sum of 2 real projective planes, can carry a non-negatively curved metric. (This follows from the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem)  and [topological classification of surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)) with non-negative Euler characteristic.)

> What happens when $n>2$?  For which $n>2$ it is known that there are infinitely many homeomorphism/ homotopy types of $n$-manifolds which can carry a Riemannian metric with non-negative sectional curvature?

Comment: Connected sum of 2 real projective planes is the Klein bottle, it indeed has a Riemannian metric of curvature 0.

Comment: Once it's true for a given dimension I imagine it's going to be true for all higher dimensions, by taking products with flat tori. I believe, however, that there are still only finitely many in dimension 3: the manifolds of constant curvature +1 and 0, and $S^2 \times S^1$.

Comment: @ Mike Miller,  there are infinitely many topologically distinct $3$-manifolds that are locally isometric to $S^{3}$

Comment: clearly there are already infinitely many $L(p,q)$... a stupid comment on my part. Thanks.

Comment: The comments of MikeMiller and NickL taken together look like they settle the question. But is the answer known in any dimensions $\ge 4$ with the additional assumption of simple connectivity?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the first dimension where an infinite family of pairwise non-homeomorphic closed nonnegatively curved manifolds occurs is $3$ (the lens spaces). The question becomes more challenging for simply-connected manifolds. If (as expected) simply-connected nonnegatively curved manifolds are rationally elliptic, then the first infinite family occurs in dimension 6, see 
[Curvature, diameter, and quotient manifolds](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/curv.pdf) by
B. Totaro.  In general, the question is well-studied and there are many examples (easily found by searching online).